# Start ASP.NET Core API locally on specific URL like localhost:port/root/

Tags: asp.net, .net, debugging, devops

I have 2 ordinary ASP.NET Core APIs.

When I run API in debug mode in Visual Studio it starts on `https://localhost:1234/` (1234 is random port here).

I want to run these 2 APIs locally with URLs `https://localhost:1234/first/` and `https://localhost:1234/second/`. I need these APIs to be available for debug in VS.

If it's not possible to run 2 APIs on the same port, then it will be interesting to know how to start them at least with specific URLs like `https://localhost:1111/first/` and `https://localhost:2222/second/`

What are the easiest way to achieve this? Is there any way to do it by modifying launchSettings.json?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run 2 different applications using the same port.
You need to modify one application (launchsettings.json) to run on a different port.
I you want the /first and /second available, you must create both (endpoints, controllers, whatever) in the same project.